# Python Shiny - how to stop the app when the user closes the browser?

Tags: python, py-shiny

In R, there are solutions to stop the App when the user closes the browser, such as

```
# in server.R
session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })
```

Is there some similar solution for python ?

I found this proposed solution, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
# In server: this closes the session when the user exits out on their browser
@reactive.Effect
@reactive.event(input.close)
async def _():
    await session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need for my shiny app, just tried it with the docs and it worked:

I created an UI button to close the app :

```
ui.input_action_button(id="exit", label="Close App")
```

After that in the server I use

```
@reactive.Effect
@reactive.event(input.exit)
async def _():
     await session.close()
```

Make sure you dont import session from shiny so the object dont get confused